# Using regex to extract based on a recurring pattern excluding newline characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as follows:

```
27223525
 
West Food Group B.V.9
 
52608670
 
Westcon
 
Group European Operations Netherlands Branch
 
30221053
 
Westland Infra Netbeheer B.V.
 
27176688
 
Wetransfer  85 B.V.
 
34380998
 
WETRAVEL B.V.
 
70669783
```

This string contains many newline characters, I wanted to explicitly ignore these as well as all multidigits with 6 or more numbers. I  came up with the following regex expression:

```
[^\n\d{6,}].+
```

This almost takes me there as it returns all the company names, however in cases where the company name itself contains a new line character these get returned as two different company names. For instance `Westcon` is a match and `Group European Operations Netherlands Branch` is also a match. I would like to tweak the above expression to make sure that the final match is `Westcon European Operations Netherlands Branch`. What regex concepts should I use to achieve this?

### Edit

I tried the following based on the comment below but got the wrong result

```
text = 'West Food Group B.V.9\n \n52608670\n \nWestcon\n \nGroup European Operations Netherlands Branch\n \n30221053\n \nWestland Infra Netbeheer B.V.\n \n27176688\n \nWetransfer 85 B.V.\n \n34380998\n \nWETRAVEL B.V.\n \n70669783\n \nWeWork Companies (International) B.V.\n \n61501220\n \nWeWork Netherlands B.V.\n \n61505439\n \nWexford Finance B.V.\n \n27124941\n \nWFC\n-\nFood Safety B.V.\n \n11069471\n \nWhale Cloud Technology Netherlands B.V.\n \n63774801\n \nWHILL Europe B.V.\n \n72465700\n \nWhirlpool Nederland B.V.\n \n20042061\n \nWhitaker\n-\nTaylor Netherlands B.V.\n \n66255163\n \nWhite Oak B.V.\n'

re.findall(r'[^\n\d{6,}](?:(?:[a-z\s.]+(\n[a-z\s.])*)|.+)',text)
```

Comment: I am currently using https://regex101.com/ with python flavor with the aim of later extending it to a python script which uses `re`

Comment: I've came up with this `[^\n\d{6,}](?:(?:[a-z\s.]+(\n[a-z\s.])*)|.+)` https://regex101.com/r/UTFMyk/1/

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'^[A-Za-z].*(?:\n(?!\d+$).*)*', contents, re.M)` where `contents` is `file.read()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you only want the company names. If so, this should work.

```
input = '''27223525

West Food Group B.V.9

52608670

Westcon

Group European Operations Netherlands Branch

30221053

Westland Infra Netbeheer B.V.

27176688

Wetransfer 85 B.V.

34380998

WETRAVEL B.V.

70669783

'''

company_name_regex = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z].*|[A-Za-z].*\d{1,5}.*', input)

pprint(company_name_regex)

['West Food Group B.V.9',
 'Westcon',
 'Group European Operations Netherlands Branch',
 'Westland Infra Netbeheer B.V.',
 'Wetransfer 85 B.V.'
 'WETRAVEL B.V.']
```

Comment: please see edits above. Companies may have digits anywhere in there name. For this dataset the number of digits within any one company name is always below 6. The number digits I want to exclude are always above 6.

Comment: Yes, I noted that the input example changed, so I have updated my answer.

Comment: Doesn't look correct as it matches `Westcon` as a separate match and remaining part as a separate match.

Comment: So does Westcon always get linked to Group European Operations Netherlands Branch?

Answer (score 1):

This will create one group for lines that don't have numbers.

regex: `/(?!(\d{6,}|\n))[a-zA-Z .\n]+/g`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/MMLGw6/1

Comment: except some company names have numbers below six digits. I have edited the question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

If you can solve this without regex it *should* be solved without regex:

```
useful = []

for line in text.split():
    if line.strip() and not line.isdigit():
        useful.append(line)
```

That should work - more or less.  Replying from my phone so can't test.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your company names starts with a letter, you may use this regex with `re.M` modifier:

```
^[a-zA-Z].*(?:\n+[a-zA-Z].*)*(?=\n+\d{6,}$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X7XGiy/2)

In python:

```
regex = re.compile(r"^[a-zA-Z].*(?:\n+[a-zA-Z].*)*(?=\n+\d{6,}$)", re.M)
```

This matches a line that starts with `[a-zA-Z]` until end of line and then matches more lines separated by `\n` that also start with `[a-zA-Z]` characters.

`(?=\n+\d{6,}$)` is a lookahead assertion to make sure our company names have a newline and 6+ digits ahead.